# HOG Descriptor With Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have been working with the Hog Descriptor in Python but I can't seem to find a clear documentation. Can anyone please explain the paramteres, the type of the input required and the output.
This is an implemntation that I found :

```
winSize = (4, 4)
blockSize = (4, 4)
blockStride = (4, 4)
cellSize = (4, 4)
nbins = 9
derivAperture = 1
winSigma = 4.
histogramNormType = 0
L2HysThreshold = 2.0000000000000001e-01
gammaCorrection = 0
nlevels = 64
winStride = (4, 4)
padding = (4, 4)
locations = ((10, 20),)
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor(winSize,blockSize,blockStride,cellSize,nbins,derivAperture,winSigma,
                        histogramNormType,L2HysThreshold,gammaCorrection,nlevels)
res = hog.compute(im,winStride,padding,locations)
```

Comment: please see this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/hog-histogram-of-oriented-gradients-67ecd887675f) and this [tutorial](https://learnopencv.com/histogram-of-oriented-gradients)

Comment: [opencv doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d33/structcv_1_1HOGDescriptor.html#ac0544de0ddd3d644531d2164695364d9) is not clear ?